# Propel behavior i18n and archivable

Tags: internationalization, archive, propel

I am using propel and i set two behaviours onto one of my tables:

```
<behavior name="archivable" />
<behavior name="i18n">
  <parameter name="i18n_columns" value="name" />
  <parameter name="default_locale" value="de" />
</behavior>
```

The problem is, that if I archive an object of that table then the field "name" is not saved. Apparently in the "copyInto" Method of the Base-Class there is no

```
$copyObj->setName($this->getName());
```

Is that a bug in propel or am I missing somethhing here?

Comment: Just a guess here, but the `archivable` behavior creates a new table for the archive based on the current table and copies data into it on save/delete. Since the `i18n` behavior creates a new table and removes columns from the desired table, `archivable` won't see those removed columns. I don't think there is any way around this, but you could clone the behavior and try to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

You have to archive the i18n information manually by making the table archivable, too, and by overriding the generated archive() method. An example is given in the Propel blog:

```
class Book extends BaseBook
{
  public function archive(PropelPDO $con = null)
  {
    // archive the book reviews
    BookReviewQuery::create()
      ->filterByBook($this)
      ->archive($con);
    // archive the current object
    return parent::archive($con);
  }
}
```

source: http://propel.posterous.com/introducing-archivable-behavior-and-why-softd